# How to append to a react app DOM using vanilla javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm creating a chrome extension that allows me to highlight text from any website.

Just to give you an idea

```
var newDom = document.body.innerHTML;
var selection = window.getSelection();
var segment = new RegExp(selection.toString(), "g");
      newDom = newDom.replace(
        segment,
        '<span style="background: red;">' + selection + "</span>"
      );
document.body.innerHTML = newDom;
```

It works. Even though I removed all the none essentials. I'm doing something to the of the website and appending it back.

This is a chrome extension, so if this ran on a react application, the said application would not work!

[Here isa demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/headless-resonance-nh09n)

To emulate the extension I added the vanilla javascript on a separate file

Comment: "This is a chrome extension, so if this ran on a react application, the said application would not work" why not?

Comment: @JaredSmith that's what I'm trying to find out.

Comment: Works for me. Make sure you don't add your elements into React container (`root` in this case), React could flip out. **PS!** All your "toolpicks" are using the same `id`, it must be unique on page.

Comment: @Solo But the counter doesn't work after you have clicked the "toolpick",  (also, next step would be to remove "toolpick" but that's kind of easy. )